# Java Enum with numeric values

Tags: android, enums

New to Java, but I've done some .Net programming. I'm wondering if Java has the equivalent of a .Net eum? Below is an example. I know Java has enum, but you can't assign values to it.

In .Net I could do an enum with values. When used in code I don't have to comment or, when writing new procedures, remember what 0, 1, 2, and 3 represent. I could also use the enum as parameter type in a constructor and then pass AccessType.Full, for instance, in as an argument.

How can I duplicate this is Android Studio?

```
Public Class Delete

    Private Enum AccessType
        Full = 0
        ReadOnly = 1
        Delete = 2
        Add = 3
    End Enum

    Private Sub DeleteIem(sItem As String)
        If User.Access = AccessType.Delete Or User.Access = AccessType.Full Then
            'delete something here
        Else
            MsgBox("You do not have access to delete these items.", vbInformation
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

In Android Studio I have the if{} block below.

```
if (AllLists.get(pos).Access == 0) {
    MsgText += getResources().getString(R.string.info_cat_shared_no) + "\n";
}
else if (AllLists.get(pos).Access == 1){
    MsgText += getResources().getString(R.string.info_cat_shared_edit) + "\n";
}
else if (AllLists.get(pos).Access == 2){
    MsgText += getResources().getString(R.string.info_cat_shared_no_edit) + "\n";
}
```

It would turn the code in to below and I wouldn't have to always be checking what 0, 1 ,2, & 3 represent. I looked up Java enums and they are just a list of string, which doesn't work for this, or at least not that I can think to implement it.

```
if (AllLists.get(pos).Access == AccessType.Full) {
    MsgText += getResources().getString(R.string.info_cat_shared_no) + "\n";
}
else if (AllLists.get(pos).Access == AccessType.ReadOnly){
    MsgText += getResources().getString(R.string.info_cat_shared_edit) + "\n";
}
else if (AllLists.get(pos).Access == AccessType.Delete){
    MsgText += getResources().getString(R.string.info_cat_shared_no_edit) + "\n";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Enum return Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792110/java-enum-return-int)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, java enums are a pretty handy object.
You can add properties, even methods, if you want.  To assign properties, just add the value as an argument to the contructor as in:

```
public enum AccessType {
    Full(0),
    ReadOnly(1),
    Delete(2),
    Add(3);
    private final int code;

    AccessType(int code) {
        this.code = code
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. I read two or three examples of Java enums and neither showed how to add values like this. They were days of the week or colors, or something else with just strings. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this page from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

You would have something like this for your ENUM (code untested):

```
public enum AccessType
{
    Full(0),
    ReadOnly(1),
    Delete(2),
    Add(3);

    AccessType(int type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

But the constructor by itself may not be necessary since you can use a switch case like this:

```
switch(AllLists.get(pos).Access)
{
    case Full:
        // ...
        break;

    case ReadOnly:
        // ...
        break;

    case Delete:
        // ...
        break;

    case Add:
        // ...
        break;
}
```