# Is it correct to use "final static" or "static final"?

Tags: java

How to use final in static class? Which way is true ?

```
private final static class
```

or

```
private static final class
```

Comment: The order of these modifiers is not significant. Please check the [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html) if you want.

Comment: Such questions should be first tried, then "answer should be found"

Comment: First Try -> Any error ? --> its wrong, No error -> then its right

Comment: @user2864740 I agree.. the "context" here was java syntax :)

Comment: static final is preferred according to JLS!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use any. No Problem. 
Nothing wrong and there is no order. as a standard we are using this as `private static final class` but again there is nothing wrong of using both.

Answer (score 2):

Either of them is fine. There is no real difference, although there is no such thing as static class in java.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java) to know how to make a class static.

Comment: What about static nested classes?

Comment: yeah I guess static nested classes are present... my mistake..