# How to register a static class in Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey

I have a class of which only static methods are to be accessed via `@path` annotations and which does not have a public constructor. My simpilified program is:

```
@Path("")
static class MyStaticClass
{
  private MyStaticClass() {...}
 @Get @Path("time")
  static public String time()
  {
     return Instant.now().toString();
  }
}
```

Running and calling "time" gives me the following error:

```
WARNUNG: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [...] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in [...] class.
```

Comment: You have any real need that this class MUST be static?

Comment: Java has no top-level static class, similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7486050/339286).

Comment: To clarify: I mean "static class" as a short cut for "class with only static methods", like java.util.Arrays or java.util.Collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, according to the [JSR](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/index.html), paragraph 3.1.2

> Root resource classes are instantiated by the JAX-RS runtime and MUST
>   have a public constructor for which the JAX-RS runtime can provide all
>   parameter values. Note that a zero argument constructor is permissible
>   under this rule.

You can use the [Adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and create JAX-RS resource (POJO with @Path) which simply delegates to your static class.  This would be very easy to understand for those coming behind you.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this answer, though I'm convinced it is the cause of my issue. An example would be great. I'm using a static inner class which is probably the issue. It used to work with my older Jersey libraries. I only started having this issue with Jersey 2.26 after being forced to upgrade.

Comment: Actually, my issue was I renamed my Main class but was still calling the old Main class. So mine was a result of not using maven correctly. The hidden dangers of renaming a class...

Answer (score 1):

The @Path annotation is designed to define a resource at the class level. The method to execute isn't controlled by @Path, but by @GET, @POST, @PUT, @HEAD, etc... with @GET as the desired operation in your case.

Your class for the "time" resource should look like this:

```
@Path("/time")
public class TimeResource { 
    @GET
    public static String time(){
        return Instant.now().toString();
    }
}
```

You could theoretically define each function as a static nested class within one "main" class:

```
public class MyResource{

    @Path("/time")
    public static final class TimeResource {    
        @GET
        public static String do(){
            return Instant.now().toString();
        }
    }

    @Path("/doSomethingElse")
    public static final class DoSomethingElseResource { 
        @GET
        public static String do(){
            // DO SOMETHING ELSE
        }
    }       
}
```

Though I don't know if that would work, you'd have to try it. I don't think there's much advantage in having them all in one class like that, though.

Comment: Oh thanks I forgot the @Get statement, added it now.