# Spring Boot - Could not find a suitable constructor error

Tags: java, spring-boot, constructor, jersey, command-line-arguments

Hi I am trying to read a file as an argument from the main class and accessing the argument in another class in Spring boot.
The main class looks like this

```
public class DemorestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    new DemorestApplication().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemorestApplication.class)).run(args);

    new UsersResources(args[0]);

}
}
```

And I am passing an argument to another class named UsersResources constructor

```
@Path("/sample")
public class UsersResources {

private String value;
UsersResources(String value){
    this.value=value;
}

//new code
@GET
@Path("Data/file/{path}")
@Produces("application/json")

public Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>> getApplicationName1(@PathParam("path") String path) throws IOException  {
ReadExceldy prop = new ReadExceldy();
FileInputStream Fs = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+value);
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Fs);
String Loc=properties.getProperty("filepath"); 
String Na=path;
String filename=Loc+Na;
return prop.fileToJson(filename);
}
}
```

I'm trying to run this code but it's throwing an error saying

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.springsampleapplication.UsersResources class
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to register a static class in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549005/how-to-register-a-static-class-in-jersey)

Comment: can't able to relate to that question .

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with Spring trying to initialize `UsersResources` class and expecting a constructor with no arguments, when you have it only with a `String` parameter. Try adding such constructor: `public UsersResources() {}`

Other thought that came into mind is that this could be because of `UsersResources` constructor not having a visibility modifier (it means it is package protected), you could try adding `public` visibility modifier to it (though Spring should be able to initialize even private constructors). Are the `DemorestApplication` and `UsersResources` classes in the same package though? As otherwise the code should not compile, since `UsersResources(String value)` is not visible outside of the package it is in. But the error is a bit different in such case: `The constructor xxx is undefined`, so probably this is not the case.

Comment: the DemorestApplication and UsersResources classes are in the same package! @Adomas

Comment: I tried adding the public visibility modifier to the UserResources constructor. It's throwing the same error! Could not find a suitable constructor in com.springsampleapplication.UsersResources class , at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na] @Adomas

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are using Jersey you need to have a `public` constructor:

> Root resource classes are instantiated by the JAX-RS runtime and MUST have a public constructor for which the JAX-RS runtime can provide all parameter values. Note that a zero argument constructor is permissible under this rule.

See [How to register a static class in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549005/how-to-register-a-static-class-in-jersey)

Comment: I tried adding the public visibility modifier to the UserResources constructor. It's throwing the same error! Could not find a suitable constructor in com.springsampleapplication.UsersResources class , 
 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:192) ~[jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:na]@kdowbecki

Comment: Trying your code sample results in `ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean` exception due to my test project setup. Is there anything more to your setup? Can you please provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined a constructor in your class, no default constructor is generated.  A work around is to make this class a Spring component with @Component et al.