# How to inherit parent's inner class in this code?

Tags: java, generics

Below is the parent class `DblyLinkList`

```
package JavaCollections.list;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class DblyLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T>{

    class DListNode<T> {

        private T item;
        private DListNode<T> prev;
        private DListNode<T> next;

        DListNode(T item, DListNode<T> p, DListNode<T> n) {
            this.item = item;
            this.prev = p;
            this.next = n;
        }


    }
.....
}
```

Below is the derived class `LockableList`,

```
  package JavaCollections.list;

    import JavaCollections.list.DblyLinkList.DListNode;

    public class LockableList<T> extends DblyLinkList<T> {

        class LockableNode<T> extends DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T> {

            /**
             * lock the node during creation of a node.
             */
            private boolean lock;

            LockableNode(T item, DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T> p,
                    DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T> n) {
                super(item, p, n); // this does not work
                this.lock = false;
            }

        }

        LockableNode<T> newNode(T item, DListNode<T> prev, DListNode<T> next) {
            return new LockableNode(item, prev, next);
        }

        public LockableList() {
            this.sentinel = this.newNode(null, this.sentinel, this.sentinel);
        }


    .....
 }
```

If `class LockableNode<T> extends DListNode<T>` in the above code, **error**:`The constructor DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T>(T, DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T>, DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T>) is undefined` occurs at line `super(item, p, n)`

This error is resolved by saying:  `class LockableNode<T> extends DblyLinkList<T>.DListNode<T>`

How do I understand this error? Why it got resolved?

Comment: Try making the `DListNode` protected: `protected class DListNode {...}`

Comment: Does `this(item, p, n);` work, instead of `super`?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson That's not the problem because if that was the case, the error message would be different. Also note they're in the same package, so it is definitely not a visibility problem.

Comment: @Craig `this(item, p, n)` would result in a `StackOverflowError` due to infinite recursion.

Comment: @m0skit0 oops. Yeah you're right. :-P Sorry didn't see that it had the same signature.

Comment: @m0skit0 Is there redeclaration of  `T`  here? when I say, `public class DblyLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T>{..}`?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, maybe that's the problem. I think that's what Hoopje is stating in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32306804/898478).

Comment: @m0skit0 No, Hoopje is talking about `DListNode `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redeclaring the type variable `T` in the inner class. That means that within the inner class, the `T` of the outer class is hidden and cannot be referred to anymore.

Since you have a non-static inner class, you can just remove the type variable `T` there:

```
class DListNode { ... }
```

because it inherits it from the containing class (and probably you mean that the variables are the same, anyway).

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. `class DListNode implements Iterable<T>{..}` or `class DListNode { ..}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `DListNode`, which does not implement `Iterable<T>`.

Comment: If you see `java.util.Map<K,V>`, you have `Entry<K,V>` as inner `interface`. So, why can't I make `DListNode<T>` instead of `DListNode`?