# Abstract vs No instance approach?

Tags: java, oop, static, abstract-class, static-methods

I have one class (class util) for generating password(it has only one public  static method ). Here two ways are : To  make it abstract so no one can create its instance

```
public abstract  class PasswordGenerator {

  public static String randomstring(int lo, int hi) {
     // Some logic , doesn't matter 
      return "";
  }
}
```

or to make its constructor `private`. So What's the best approach to do that ?

```
public class PasswordGenerator {

  private PasswordGenerator() {

  }

  public static String randomstring(int lo, int hi) {
    // Some logic , doesn't matter 
    return "";
  }
}
```

So What's the best approach to do that ?

Comment: what you want achieve by this ?!

Comment: Does java not have static classes? Dang

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static Classes In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java)

Comment: What you're wanting to do is create a **singleton**.  Look for the singleton pattern in Java, or see the answer by @mad_manny

Comment: @KoosGadellaa I disagree, as far as we know the OP doesn't need a singleton because he didn't mention stateful operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make both the class `final` and the constructor `private`.

With the `final` keyword you clearly express the intent that the class is not made to be **inherited**.
With the `private` constructor you clearly express the intent that the class is not made to be **instanciated**.

```
public final class PasswordGenerator {

  private PasswordGenerator() {}

  public static String randomstring(int lo, int hi) {
    // Some logic , doesn't matter 
    return "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely not make the class abstract, as this might indicate to other developers, that it is intended to be extended (and therefor instantiated).

Having a class technically being able to be instantiated is a minor problem.

But in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java) you can see a workaround, that uses a private constructor in combination with making the class final.