# Static vs Non-Static Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static

I am looking at the Fragment documentation from
[Google Android Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

I have been using `Fragments` created by Android Studio that is non-static
For Example:

```
public class FormsFragment extends Fragment
```

Why is Google's documentation declaring them as static? What is the reasoning?

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment
```

Comment: Keyword static at top level class declaration means nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java

Comment: @RomanSamoylenko so what's the point of declaring them static at the top level? They just feel like messing with us?

Comment: When I try to declare a top level class `static` I get a compiler warning. So either you found a bug in the documentation or the snippet is really located within another class...

Comment: That is right, top level class cannot be static as well as meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fragments you have to follow the contracts given by Android itself. Since the framework manages your activity and fragment lifecycle, it needs to be able to create these classes. This is done with a public default constructor. Also it's required to declare the class itself public.

So if you define the fragment as a "normal" class, you don't have to consider anything else. If you define it as an inner class of another class **must** declare it static as well. Otherwise the class will have an implicit constructor with a parameter of the type of the outer class and therefore no public default constructor to create a new instance of your fragment.

Comment: could you provide a use case in which you would nest a Fragment? I always use them as the top class.

Comment: There's no difference in the resulting class. It's just the developers preference to keep it in the same class file as the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems that you are classifying fragments by two types . Static and non static, but it is not, there are two types of fragment `Static` and `Dynamic` .The keyword static doesn't mean that this is a static fragment . the keyword probably means that that fragment class was a nested inner class , which only can be accessed top level class(probably an activity ).