# How can I use an interface as type in java?

Tags: java, initializer

I have created an interface named `Leen` and created a class X that implements this interface, but when i go to main class to create a variable named `x` like this

```
Leen x;
x.printname();
```

The compiler gives me error:

`Connect.java:10: error: variable x might not have been initialized`

Comment: Is there any line like `x = new LeenImpl();`?

Comment: Not with that code it doesn't, as you don't have a variable called `p`. It would say that `x` might not have been initialized though, and it's right. This has nothing to do with interfaces though. You'd get the same issue if you wrote, say, `String x; x.length();`

Comment: Also note that in your code, `x` isn't a *class*, it's a variable. You say you've created "class x" to implement the interface - that's not what you've shown at all. Please provide a [mcve] to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Ok I have this classes a) main class b) interface have method to print my name c) class App implements my interface okey ? Problem when I goto main class and I try to create variable from my class name app to use like this App Myvar like String x or int z ? How I can do that ?

Comment: Note : in my class app I have implementation from interface .. that mean I do override for the method response about print my name

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an interface without implementation. Implementation can be a concrete class or abstract class which implements your interface. Based on your code, clearly there is no implementation for you interface. I'm also not sure where did you use the variable `p`. Kindly provide your whole class so that we can help you.

Comment: Ok I have this classes a) main class b) interface have method to print my name c) class App implements my interface okey ? Problem when I goto main class and I try to create variable from my class name app to use like this App Myvar like String x or int z ? How I can do that ?

Comment: Note : in my class app I have implementation from interface .. that mean I do override for the method response about print my name

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if u want to access in the variable with out instantiating it u can make the variable static in the class. say `App` is ur class name and xyz is ur interface.

```
class App implements xyz{
    public static int x;
    public static void printme(){
        //Your code goes here...
    }

}
```

Now u can access that from ur mainclass like

```
App app= null;
app.x= 6;
app.printme();
```

Comment: Ok Murali I don't need to create object .. I need to create Data type like int x or string s and call the method example : Myclass V ; how I can do that?

Comment: Then make the method or the variable which u want to access to static type in your class.@SaifAl-Bashiti

Comment: You are mean java use static feasibility on class integer and another class (double,float ) ? To make all user can use the class whitout need to create object ?

Comment: yes. Check my updated answer. Let me know if that works for u.@SaifAl-Bashiti

Comment: Ok now I understand but answer me please .. static define in class like this .. Static class Saif {} true ?

Comment: Please refer the following link for more understanding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java @SaifAl-Bashiti

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, it's because you declared the variable but never instantiated it, meaning it does not exsist yet, it's just a placeholder for the type defined at the declaration, what you need to do is

```
Leen x; // declare the variable
x = new implementationClass(); // instantiate the variable

x.PrintName(); // then you functions
```

Now since the interface is used, all functions on the interface is available, but the code will attempt to use the implementation form whatever class implemented the interface and was intantiated

Why is this smart ? well say you lave a `List<Leen>` then all elements in the list can use the functions on `Leen` regardless of what implementation of `Leen` they were created with

Comment: I need to define a data type from interface like double z ... Here I don't need to create instance from double class only write class name and variable

Comment: in that case you are refering to Wrappers, simply make the implementation have a setx() and getx() then in the implementation have x stored and acces it through the interface using getx() and setx()

Also interfaces and other abstract classes are impossible to acces unless implemented and initialised