# do you have to make class static if no non-static class members?

Tags: java, variables, methods, static, instance

Is it a good practice to make all the methods in a class static if the class doesn't have any non-static class members? 
Like some sort of managers that don't have any instance variables of their own.

Comment: Actually, I'd argue that it's best NOT to make all the methods of such a class static.  But I think it's a matter of opinion.  I wouldn't be too surprised if someone argues the opposite.

Comment: Note that static methods can't implement interfaces. You may want your class to implement an interface, even if it lacks instance fields.

Comment: @Andy good point. i.e. the java.lang.Runnable interface https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html
so instances can be executed on a thread.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is never going to have an instance, all the methods should be static, it would be the only way to call them (you can't do `myInst.myFunc()` because `myInst` can't exist).

This may be relevant : [Static Classes In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java)

The `Math` example is a good one, it would be confusing to have to do

```
Math myCalculator = new Math()
myCalculator.multiply(x,y);
```

unless `myCalculator` could have a different definition of PI, E, etc.

So in short, yes, a class that has no non-static members should have nothing but static methods

Edit : Andy Thomas made a good point

Your `Math` might implement the `Multiplies` interface, because it can multiply two things. At the same time, my `MultiplierAndAdder` class (I know it's a terrible class, but for the example) also implements `Multiplies`. In this case, the methods MUST be non-static, and you must instantiate an instance in order to pass it to whatever will be using it.

The interface logic has always been in my mind (as taught by a prof) : square peg, round hole. If you want to fit through the round hole, you have to be round. If you don't exist, you're not round, and can't go through the hole.