# Calling for function

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity

I wrote code for SQLite project, and wrote function, that had to use this code. Now I want to attach this function to a button, that appears in another activity. How can I do that? I tried to make onClickListener, or write function in onCreate of main acitivity, but I didn't quite got result.

This is my function:

```
  private void insertInDB(Seifim seifim){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO seifim (misparRehev, shemEhida, sugTipul, kamutKilometrim, date, manoa, delek, higui, blamim, zmigim, hashmal, hashlada, abs, mivhan) values('" +
            seifim.getMisparRehev() + "','" + seifim.getShemEhida() + "','" + seifim.getSugTipul() + "','" + seifim.getKamutKilometrim() + "','" +
            seifim.getDate() + "','" + seifim.getManoa() + "','" + seifim.getDelek() + "','" + seifim.getHigui() + "','" +
            seifim.getBlamim() + "','" + seifim.getZmigim() + "','" + seifim.getHashmal() + "','" + seifim.getHashlada() + "','" +
            seifim.getAbs() + "','" + seifim.getMivhan();
    db.execSQL(sql);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tofes was saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: When I wrote my function in main activity, it asked for attributes and I have no idea what to insert.

Comment: I recommend You to make constants from strings or another values

Comment: I guess that You can make it by using static classes like Math.class in java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method from other activities you should make it public and then put the name of your activity and then the name of the method

Like this,

```
SecondActivity.insertInDB(args);
```

You constructed the method this way

```
 private void insertInDB(Seifim seifim) {}
```

This means you should pass an instance of `Seifim` from MainActivity to the method call

```
Seifim seifim = new Seifim();
//set all the param to the object and then pass it to the method
SecondActivity.insertInDB(seifim);
```

If you don't want to create a Seifim in MainActivity you should either rewrite your method so you won't pass the args and call it from MainActivity there or make your instance of Seifim from SecondActivity static.