# javac: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, javac

I know I'm doing something stupid here.  I'm trying to compile java from the command line with java/javac.  I've looked through many answers to this and just can't get it.  I can compile and run our good friend HelloWorld.java with no problems.  I'm trying to compile code from *Java 8 In Action*.  The .java file is:

```
package lambdasinaction.chap1;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
public class FilteringApples{
    // public static void main(String ... args){
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Apple> inventory = Arrays.asList(new Apple(80,"green"),
                                              new Apple(155, "green"),
                                              new Apple(120, "red"));   
        List<Apple> greenApples = filterApples(
            inventory, FilteringApples::isGreenApple);
        System.out.println(greenApples);
        List<Apple> heavyApples = filterApples(
            inventory, FilteringApples::isHeavyApple);
        System.out.println(heavyApples);
        List<Apple> greenApples2 = filterApples(inventory,
            (Apple a) -> "green".equals(a.getColor()));
        System.out.println(greenApples2);
        List<Apple> heavyApples2 = filterApples(inventory,
            (Apple a) -> a.getWeight() > 150);
        System.out.println(heavyApples2);
        List<Apple> weirdApples = filterApples(inventory,
            (Apple a) -> a.getWeight() < 80 || "brown".equals(a.getColor()));
        System.out.println(weirdApples);
    }
    public static List<Apple> filterGreenApples(List<Apple> inventory){
        List<Apple> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Apple apple: inventory){
            if ("green".equals(apple.getColor())) {
                result.add(apple);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static List<Apple> filterHeavyApples(List<Apple> inventory){
        List<Apple> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Apple apple: inventory){
            if (apple.getWeight() > 150) {
                result.add(apple);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static boolean isGreenApple(Apple apple) {
        return "green".equals(apple.getColor()); 
    }
    public static boolean isHeavyApple(Apple apple) {
        return apple.getWeight() > 150;
    }
    public static List<Apple> filterApples(
            List<Apple> inventory, Predicate<Apple> p){
        List<Apple> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Apple apple : inventory){
            if(p.test(apple)){
                result.add(apple);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }       
    public static class Apple {
        private int weight = 0;
        private String color = "";
        public Apple(int weight, String color){
            this.weight = weight;
            this.color = color;
        }
        public Integer getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }
        public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
            this.weight = weight;
        }
        public String getColor() {
            return color;
        }
        public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Apple{" +
                   "color='" + color + '\'' +
                   ", weight=" + weight +
                   '}';
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it with "javac -cp . FilterApples.java" and it compiles with no errors or warnings.  I get two class files: FilteringApples$Apple.class  FilteringApples.class.  I'v tried various ways to run it including "java -cp . FilterApples" and "java -cp . lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples".  It always comes back with

```
Error: Could not find or load main class lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples
```

Output from javap is:

```
Compiled from "FilteringApples.java"
public class lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples {
  public lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  ...
```

It was suggested that this is a [duplicate of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928).  I looked at that question in researching this one and the suggestions didn't work.  Also, As I said, I can compile HelloWorld.java with no problems.  I think there is something different here.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

**NOTE**: "java HelloWorld" worked fine but java "FilterApples" failed in same directory because HelloWorld has no package statement but FilterApples does:

```
package lambdasinaction.chap1;
```

Comment: Pls check if you need to update the inner class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java

Comment: Which directory are you in when you run `java -cp . lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples`?  You need to be in the directory _above_ the one called `lambdasinaction`.

Comment: You run the java command in the wrong directory, using the wrong class name. Nicely explained in that duplicate question. And: javap is less sensitive. javap doesn't care about the class path. It just shows you what is in your files. The JVM isn't that robust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows:

Assuming the current directory is `C:\Temp\sample`

**Step 1**

Create directories `lambdasinaction\chap1` and put file `FilteringApples.java` there

**Step 2**

While being in `C:\Temp\sample` compile the code: `javac lambdasinaction\chap1\FilteringApples.java`. After this step, the expected output is:

```
C:\temp\sample>tree /F
C:.
└───lambdasinaction
    └───chap1
            FilteringApples$Apple.class
            FilteringApples.class
            FilteringApples.java
```

**Step 3**

While being in `C:\Temp\sample` run the code: `java lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples`

The expected output is:

```
C:\temp\sample>java lambdasinaction.chap1.FilteringApples
[Apple{color='green', weight=80}, Apple{color='green', weight=155}]
[Apple{color='green', weight=155}]
[Apple{color='green', weight=80}, Apple{color='green', weight=155}]
[Apple{color='green', weight=155}]
[]
```

Comment: I'm gettng spoiled by using an IDE I'm afraid.  "for x in `find . -name \*.java`; do javac $x; done` compiled from the right directory compiled everything just fine :) Thanks ALL!