# Why does it not work? Error line marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(1, 14, 12, "Poliklinika"));

Tags: java

It is not working, any sugestions? No enclosing instance on line marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(1, 14, 12, "Poliklinika")); . Tryed to fix it fore hours, please help me. ANother error is on line "marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(1, 14, 12, "Poliklinika"));".
    package savarankiskas;

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.print.DocFlavor.STRING;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class savarankiskas {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{


        ArrayList<Marsrutas> marsrutai = new ArrayList<Marsrutas>();

        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(1, 14, 12, "Poliklinika"));
        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(2, 18, 13, "Rozyno mokykla"));
        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(3, 17, 14, "Tulpiu"));
        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(4, 11, 16, "Parko"));
        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(5, 22, 17, "Centras"));
        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(6, 10, 18, "Kniaudiskes"));
        marsrutai.add(new Marsrutas(7, 9, 10, "Stetiskes"));


        System.out.println("Tai yra marsrutu informacine baze. Siuo metu esantys irasai :");
 for(int i = 0 ; i < marsrutai.size(); i++){

          System.out.println(marsrutai.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
class Marsrutas{

        public int marsr_nr;
        public int kel_sk;
        public int laikas; 
        public String stotele;

        public Marsrutas(int marsrnr, int kelsk, int laiks, String stot){
            this.marsr_nr = marsrnr;
            this.kel_sk = kelsk;
            this.laikas = laiks;
            this.stotele = stot;
        }
public String toString(){
            return "*******Marsrutu duomenys******\n" + 
                   "Marsruto numeris: " + this.marsr_nr + "\n" +
                   "keleiviu skaicius: " + this.kel_sk + "\n" + 
                   "Suskaiciavimo laikas: " + this.laikas + "\n" +
                   "Stotele: " + this.stotele + "\n"
        }
}
}
```

Comment: second error is fixed, miseed ;

Comment: what error says

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for some more information

Answer (score 0):

class Marsrutas - this class needs to be static:

```
static class Marsrutas{
}
```

Here is an article on the meaning/necessity of implementing static classes and variables: [Static Classes In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486012/static-classes-in-java)

Comment: Or it needs to externalised or it needs to be called from within in instance context