# How can i access static class without using object in android?

Tags: java, android

Can i access static class to another class without using object for that static class. help me how to access.

Comment: Please show some code or further describe the problem - I've no idea what you're asking here? Is it really about Java, javascript and JSON?

Comment: You can directly access `static` methods. Like `MyClass.statMeth();`. You don't need to create object/instance.

Comment: you don't have time to ask a short question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your question is more of accessing class static variables/methods in another class. If so, yes you can.

```
public class TestStatic
{
public static int x =10;
}

public class YourClass
{

public void yourMethod()
{
int yourVar = TestStatic.x;
}
}
```

If you are referring accessing static inner classes, here is a good discussion [static inner class discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/java-static-class)