# how to write full code in just one class

Tags: jar, jframe, jbutton

```
 //calling class
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
      class jcheckkbox {
          public static void main(String args[]) {
jRadio roof = new jRadio();
 roof.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 roof.setSize(300, 200);
 roof.setVisible(true);



               //secondary class
     import java.awt.*;
     import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;



     public class jcheckbox extends JFrame {
            private JCheckBox cd;
            private JCheckBox md;
            private JTextField vcd;

     public jcheckbox() {
   super("Beer bar");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());

vcd = new JTextField("this is a code", 20);
vcd.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
vcd.setToolTipText("yahoo");
add(vcd);

cd = new JCheckBox("bold");
md = new JCheckBox("italic");
add(md);
add(cd);

handler dahandler = new handler();
 cd.addItemListener(dahandler);
 md.addItemListener(dahandler);

   }
      private class handler implements ItemListener {
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
    Font cool = null;
    if (md.isSelected() && cd.isSelected())
     cool = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 25);
    else if (md.isSelected())
     cool = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30);
    else if (md.isSelected())
     cool = new Font("Sans_Serif", Font.ITALIC, 30);

     vcd.setFont(cool);

  }}}
```

how to write a program in just one class i mean no need calling class for setsize or defaultcloseoperation etc because two classes are harder to compile when  making a .jar or .exe out of it,i know there is another way but i want to use this method as it is a lot more easier to make buttons,textfields comboboxes with this method

Comment: Are you, by chance, compiling your code with pencil and paper?

Comment: Using one class for everything is bad idea. All of your statements are wrong.

Comment: Maybe we can help this guy, instead of tar and feathers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your whole program is within a couple of hundred lines then you can create multiple classes within a file. A file is typically used to host one class, but you can have [static classes withing the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/java-static-class)
As per some of the comments it is bad practice to put everything in one class. A class should only do one thing and helps modularize your program.
As per your code sample above you are obviously a beginner. I would strongly recommend that you go to the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and take a look around.
If you have any further questions then Google for them, if they have not been answered, then feel free to post a question here.

Comment: ok so can you tell me how to make a jar file out of 2 classes in hand

Comment: @Himanshu are you using an IDE ? Most IDEs (Integrated Development Environments) Have helpers to create a jar file. if not the command is jar -cf jar-file file1.class file2.class filen.class

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand the questions but here is my answer as I understand first you can include the main method on your jcheckbox class.
Second you can add this functions you hinted in the constructor

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setSize(300, 200);
this.setVisible(true);

public jcheckbox()() {
super("Beer bar");
setLayout(new FlowLayout());

this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setSize(300, 200);
this.setVisible(true);

vcd = new JTextField("this is a code", 20);
vcd.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 22));
vcd.setToolTipText("yahoo");
add(vcd);

cd = new JCheckBox("bold");
md = new JCheckBox("italic");
add(md);
add(cd);


handler dahandler = new handler();
cd.addItemListener(dahandler);
md.addItemListener(dahandler);

}
```

Comment: ok so can you tell me how to make a jar file out of 2 classes in hand