# Using other's class' method?

Tags: java, class, methods, hierarchy

in `MainFrame`class there is a method named `createPerson` which takes `String id` and returns `Person` type.

and in my `Person` class there is a method `getFatherName` which returns a string.

in my `Tree` class can I do the following statement ?:

`String father = ( MainFrame.createPerson("001") ).getFatherName();`

can i do this without creating an instance of MainFrame?

edit: i cannot create an instance of MainFrame it is a main class with GUI

Comment: If `MainFrame.createPerson` is `static`

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can! If the method `MainFrame.createPerson()` is defined as a [static/class method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

You are probably already familiar with static methods, without knowing it, like the methods in [`Math`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class or [`System.exit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

These are often used as factory methods, which seems to be the case in here.

Answer (score -1):

That will only work if MainFrame is a static class.  Otherwise you will need to create an instance of MainFrame.  You can create the instance inline thought like this:

```
String father = ( new MainFrame.createPerson("001") ).getFatherName();
```

Comment: `if MainFrame is a static class` What is a static class in java? There is only static inner class, and it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You need parentheses after the constructor name.

Comment: Here is an example of how java does Static classes:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/java-static-class.  If you are unable to do an inner class then you will need to create a new object of type MainFrame.

Comment: @hav2play21: Indeed, it is a static inner class, and the top answer there says: `Only nested classes can be static. By doing so you can use the nested class without having an instance of the outer class.`. It has nothing to do with the case here.

Comment: "That will only work if" `createPerson` is a static _method_. Otherwise the example, `= new MainFrame().createPerson("001").getFatherName();` works _if_ there's a public constructor. The term "static class" is _sometimes_ used, very informally, as on this page, to mean a class with all static methods and a private constructor (so no instance can be created.)