# java threads effect on static classes

Tags: java, multithreading

consider the following code:

```
static class ThreadTest extends Thread {
    int x;
    int[] y;

    public ThreadTest(int x, int[] y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (x< 10) {
            ++x;
            System.out.print("0");
        }
        while (y[0] < 10) {
            ++y[0];
            System.out.print('1');
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x = 0;
    int[] y = new int[1];
    y[0] = 0;

    Thread A = new ThreadTest(x, y);
    Thread B = new ThreadTest(x, y);

    B.start();
    A.start();
}
```

how many 1's and how many 0's will be printed?
how can I ensure that the number of 1's will be the same every time the program runs?
notice that the class is **static**

How is it possible to evaluate the max and min  appearances of "1"?

Comment: How is `static` even relevant to the question?

Comment: I assume that there is some wrapping class and that `ThreadTest` is an inner class.

Comment: @Gray: There has to be. Only an inner class can be declared `static`.

Comment: yes there is a wrapping class

Comment: Agreed @aix.  It was a statement.  +1 on the answer.

Comment: Read what the Java memory model specifies.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, your code contains a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition) since the two threads are modifying the same `y` array. This means that the number of 1s that get printed is indeterminate.

> how can I ensure that the number of 1's will be the same every time the program runs?

You need to introduce synchronization between the two threads.

This can be done in a variety of ways. The most common one in Java is to use a `synchronized` block around the code that modifies and/or reads shared state.

An alternative way is to replace the `int[1]` array with a single [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). This would work pretty well for this particular case.

> notice that the class is static

Whether the class is `static` is totally irrelevant here. [All it means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3584151/367273) is that an instance of `ThreadTest` has no implicit reference to an instance of the outer class. It has nothing to do with the sharing of state between instances of `ThreadTest` (which I think is what you're implying here).

Comment: can you evaluate what would be the minimal and maximal appearances of "1" ?

Answer (score 0):

The min amount of 1s is obviously 10, the max amount will be 20.

20 because worst case will be that both threads reach

```
while (y[0] < 10)
```

at the same time every time, and then again reach

```
++y[0];
```

also at the same time every time, which will render one of the increments lost.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10667953/419

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the class is `static` does not play any role here.

While the `ThreadTest.y` variable is not static (and it shouldn't be), it is filled with a **reference to the same array for all you threads**. That is where your synchronization bug is: in `main` you should not be giving both threads the *same* array.