# JAVA: When should a class be static or dynamic

Tags: java, dynamic, static

I have a class that basically parses a file and stores results in a hashmap , this class should handle all files in a directory (usually <10 files) . The process is linear with a single thread.

for the sake of  best practice, should it be a static or dynamic class ?

Comment: What do you mean by "static or dynamic"? A `class` can be declared with the `static` modifier iff [it's an static nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). Please show code and attempt to explain what your question is again.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty generic task, so I would go with `static`, but I am prepared to be overruled by much more knowledgeable Java geeks. :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If calling your parsing method makes sense even when no 'object' has been created and initialized, use a `static` method

ie: do not use

```
Parser p = new Parser();
HashMap result = parser.parse("directory");
```

When you can easily do the following:

```
HashMap result = Parser.parse("directory");
```

[Java: when to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `static` modifier is appropriate if you don't have any reason to instantiate the class.

Also, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/java-static-class)  only nested classes can be called static, and when they are, you can use the nested class without making an instance of the outer class.

Comment: `abstract` is the keyword to use if there is no reason to instantiate the class. Static just means that you have access to a member without an actual instance of the the class.

Comment: @ColinD isn't `abstract` the keyword that you use when you intend other classes to inherit from the class?

Comment: Yes, it can be used for that. You make the super class abstract so that it is impossible to create an instance of it, forcing the use of a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the class, but you could make this hashmap static with public access (directly or via accessors).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic class loading is done when the name of the class is not known at compile time. I don't see reasons to use 'dynamic' modifier in your particular case.