# In scala, how class be final and abstract

Tags: java, scala, abstract, final

I am a `Java` Developer with a light background in `Scala`.

I was exploring `Scala` code on github, where I find the [Long](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/Long.scala) class is **final and abstract**; in Java AFAIK, this is impossible ([Why can't a Java class be both abstract and final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110342/why-cant-a-java-class-be-both-abstract-and-final)).

So, My question is, How this works in Scala?