# datepicker android - build errors

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

On the Android dev site I tried this datepicker http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#ShowingTheTimePicker and I added it to a new new project in my eclipse but I am getting build errors can you please help?

Why wont it work?

ERRORS:

1. The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity
2. Illegal modifier for the class DatePickerFragment; only public, abstract & final are permitted

#### Java Code:

```
package com.example.datepicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
}
```

#### Layout File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fghgffhf" 
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### DatePickerDialog:

```
package com.example.datepicker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.datepicker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.datepicker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Try keyboard combination CTRL + SHIFT + O . It will load any imports needed.

Comment: @sandeep, that won't help in this case, the Activity class does not allow access to SupportFragmentManager, only the support library subclasses do...

Answer (score 1):

1. You MainActivity needs to extend [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), which is the subclass of Activity from the support library that allows you to access support lib related methods for Fragments.
2. A class cannot be declared as static in java unless it is a nested class. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/why-are-you-not-able-to-declare-a-class-as-static-in-java) for details.