# How can I make a static class in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans prevents me from making a static class. How can I make one?

I made class like: right click on project > new > Java Class. Then I just add a static keyword on the class created.

Comment: ..and [Why are you not able to declare a class as static in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/why-are-you-not-able-to-declare-a-class-as-static-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a static class as a nested class and not the main class.
So, the Netbeans is not allowing you.

```
class MainClass {
    ...
    static class InnerClass {
        ...   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not!

Only `public`, `final` and `abstract` modifier are allowed in a Java `Class`.

However, you can write a `static`, `private` nested class. But only in nested class.

Answer (score 1):

Static class are [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). You cannot create a new class (a new file .java) marked by static modificator.