# Is there any difference between static functions, one belongs to static class, another not?

Tags: c#, static-methods

In C# I have two class with one static function. First class is defined as static and another is not.

```
public static class TestClass1
{
    public static string TestFunc()
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    public static string TestFunc()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I can call these functions as

```
TestClass1.TestFunc();
TestClass2.TestFunc();
```

What is the difference between these two type of usage, or is there any?
(This function is called more than million times in a day. My first concern is about memory and performance)

Comment: The question is *not* language agnostic, as the concept of "static class" has a completely different meaning in C# and Java - let alone other languages.

Comment: With java, a class which is not nested cannot be static, see following link     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584113/why-are-you-not-able-to-declare-a-class-as-static-in-java

Comment: I have removed the Java and language-agnostic tags, since OP is using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of C#, there is no functional difference, except that only methods in `static` classes can be declared as an *extension* methods, i.e. with a `this SomeType name` first parameter. Which neither example attempts to do here. Other than that: they are identical.

If you *aren't expecting* any instances of the type to be created (i.e. it is intended to be a utility class), then you should use `static class`. The main point of this is that it prevents creation, subclassing, etc. Prior to `static class`, in old C# versions, you would have to do:

```
public abstract class MyType {
    private MyType() {}

    // ...methods...
}
```

to get something remotely comparable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in using static functions from a static class or a non-static class. (Except the one mentioned by Marc Gravell)

The attribute 'static' for a class means: 'abstract sealed'. This indicates that such a class is intended to contain only static functions.
I think it is considered to be a better programming style, if one writes static helper-functions into a static class.