# What is a static nested class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Static vs non static inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-non-static-inner-class)

What is a static nested class? 
What is the difference between static and non-static nested classes?

Comment: Actually the question I linked above fits better than the one I voted for ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A static inner class is a class nested inside another class that has the `static` modifier. It's pretty much identical to a top-level class, except it has access to the private members of the class it's defined inside of.

```
class Outer {
    private static int x;
    static class Inner1 {
    }
    class Inner2 {
    }
}
```

Class `Inner1` is a static inner class. Class `Inner2` is an inner class that's not static. The difference between the two is that instances of the non-static inner class are permanently attached to an instance of `Outer` -- you can't create an `Inner2` without an `Outer`. You can create `Inner1` object independently, though.

Code in `Outer`, `Inner1` and `Inner2` can all access x; no other code will be allowed to.

Comment: I think you are wrong regarding:  "except it has access to the private members of the class it's defined inside of" You will get compile time error 
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field", Static class wont have access to any nonstatic member of outer/enclosing class

Comment: You are confusing the concept of access control with actually having members to access. Code in the static inner class is allowed to see all members of enclosing class in exactly the same way as code in a static method of the enclosing class would; if the static code has an instance of the enclosing class to work with, it can see all the members of that instance.

Comment: okay, got what you mean ,  :) , my bad

Comment: Perhaps show Outer2, a class which is outside of the Outer class, and compare that with Inner1/Inner2. Please.

Comment: @MrCholo Added a bit.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I meant this https://gist.github.com/the1mills/fa0e6a49008368d4ab279e8c0fc65767  but it might be outside the scope of the OP. Feel free to comment on the gist thread tho, thx.