# Annotate class for SimpleXML

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

I am trying to create pojo for this XML file, but without success

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PCOWEB t="2010-03-22 11:48 ">
<PCO>
    <INTEGER_R>
        <O I="I00000" V="73"/>
        <O I="I00001" V="21"/>
        <O I="I00002" V="0"/>
    </INTEGER_R>
    <INTEGER_RW>
        <O I="H00200" V="5050"/>
        <O I="H00201" V="0"/>
        <O I="H00202" V="0"/>
        <O I="H00203" V="0"/>
    </INTEGER_RW>
    <DIGITAL_R>
        <O I="D00000" V="0"/>
        <O I="D00001" V="1"/>
        <O I="D00002" V="0"/>
        </DIGITAL_R>
    <DIGITAL_RW>
        <O I="C00200" V="0"/>
        <O I="C00201" V="0"/>
    </DIGITAL_RW>
</PCO>
```

I started with

```
 @Root(name = "PCOWEB") //root of the xml file
public class PCOWEB {
    @Root(name = "PCO")
    public class PCO {

        })

    }

    @Element
    private String t;
}
```

but I receive an error: 
Attribute 't' does not have a match in class pojo at line 1

Answer (score 0):

First off, your XML document is not valid because it is missing the closing `</PCOWEB>` tag at the end.

There are several issues with your Java mapping class.

- There is a syntax error on line 6 of the pasted code, at the closing parenthesis (probably a copy and paste issue).
- You are annotating `t` with `@Element`. However, in your XML document, `t` is not an element but an *attribute* of the `PCO` element.
- [You cannot use inner classes with Simple XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459172/4442714). You can use static nested classes, though (cf. [loose object mapping](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#loosemap)).

Use this as a start:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.*;

@Root(strict = false) // indicates that this is a loose (partial) mapping
public class PCOWEB {

    @Root(strict = false)
    private static class PCO {
    }

    @Attribute
    private String t;

    @Element(name = "PCO")
    private PCO pco;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, at the end it looks like this:

```
@Root
public class PCOWEB {

    @Attribute (name="t")
    private String time;

    @Element
    private PCO PCO;
}

public class PCO {

    @ElementList
    private List<Entry> INTEGER_R;
    @ElementList
    private List<Entry> INTEGER_RW;
    @ElementList
    private List<Entry> DIGITAL_R;
    @ElementList
    private List<Entry> DIGITAL_RW;
}

@Element (name="O")
public class Entry {
    @Attribute (name="I")
    private String key;
    @Attribute (name="V")
    private String value;
}
```