# Why I cant create a object in extended class which has same name as inner class

Tags: java

I am try to find out why below code is giving error, Can anybody explain please.
Here is a class

```
package abc;

public class A {
   public class B {

   }
}
```

Now I am try to create a B class

```
package xyz;
import abc.*;


public class B extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B (); // this line gives error. Can you please explain
    }
}
```

Please consider class B extends A is in default package means

```
import abc.*;


public class B extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B (); // this line gives error. Can you please explain 
                          // I am try to create "B" class object which extends A 
                         //.. not the B inner class 
    }
}
```

Error shows in eclipse is : "No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type A (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of A)."

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Comment: And what exactly is the error? There is nothing wrong with types here, you may be trying to call a non-existent constructor.

Comment: if you post the error, it will be something like "enclosing class instance required". See my answer for explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 2):

Given that `B` extends `A`, and `A` contains an inner class `B`, I suspect there's room for confusion (for both compiler and programmer).

The line:

```
B b = new B();
```

is ambiguous. *Which* B is this ? As pointed out elsewhere, the inner class B needs an containing instance of `A`, so I suspect you mean the `B` outer class.

**Edit:** Your error

> "No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the
>   allocation with an enclosing instance of type A (e.g. x.new A() where
>   x is an instance of A)."

confirms this. I presume you want the `xyz.B` and should scope that appropriately.

Comment: Doesn't make sense because an inner class has to be referenced by its parent.  `A.B`

Comment: Given that we don't know what error he's getting it's possible he's triggering this precise issue

Comment: @Woot4Moo Even from the same file?

Comment: @kaykay are these in the same file?

Comment: @Woot4Moo -- don't think it does, because the outer class `B` is extending from `A`, so the inner class `B` would be within its own scope.

Comment: @BrianAgnew I want B's object which is in default package . "B extends A" 's object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the enclosing scope:

```
B b = new A.B();
```

or

```
B b = new xyz.B();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make `public class B` `static`, it will work as written.

Otherwise, you cannot make instances of class B from outside an instance of class A, because non-static inner classes require a pointer to their outer class's "this" (within a B, you can write `this.A`, and that will actually refer to the enclosing A).

Answer (score 0):

When I create the following in Eclipse:

```
package com.example;

public class A {
    class B {
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.example;

import com.example.A.B;

public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

As you can see Eclipse imports the class `A.B` .  Without the import the following error is noted:

No enclosing instance of type A is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type A (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of A).

Answer (score 0):

The error I get when I try to compile this code (minus the package specs since they seem irrelevant) is "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context".  So, the problem is that within the static method `main()` you are trying to access something non-static, which I guess is the definition of the inner class B.

You actually get the same error if the second outer class has a different name.  So the apparent naming conflict is a red herring.  Although that itself is a good reason not to use the same name for both classes -- it causes confusion when trying to understand the error.

If I change the declaration of the inner class to be static, the error is resolved.

```
public class A {
   public static class B {

   }
}
```

Some relevant discussion of static vs. non-static nested classes is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-non-static-inner-class).

But this may not be the correct fix.  It shows that your code in `main()` is referencing the `B` inner class, not the `B` class that contains the method.  Which did you actually want?  Obviously, I'd suggest using different names for this two classes to avoid confusion.  If what you want in `main()` is to create an instance of the class that contains that method, then using a unique name for that class will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `B extends A` **has inherited the class `A.B`** and the expression `new B()` refers to that inner class. Therefore it asks for an enclosing instance. You must either explicitly qualify both your mentions of `B` with the package name, or, far better, **avoid such naming mess** in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, through reflection you can create B class(B extends A class) object.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import abc.*;

public class B extends A{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //B b = new B(); // this line gives error. Can you please explain 
                          // I am try to create "B" class object which extends A 
                         //.. not the B inner class
     try{
      Class c = Class.forName("B"); //class B extends A
      Method  m=c.getMethod("print", null);
      m.invoke(c.newInstance(), null);
     }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    public void print(){
     System.out.println("Printed");
    }
}
```