# Not allowing declaration in the main method

Tags: java

//This is a small code to study how collection works but when I create an Mountain object in main method it gives an error. Explained further in the end.

```
import java. util. * ;
    public class sortMountains {
     class Mountain {
               String name;
               int height;
               Mountain(String n, int h) {
                 name      = n;

                 height = h;
               }
               public String toString( ) {
                 return name +  + height;
               }
            }
    List<Mountain> mtn  = new ArrayList<Mountain> ();
      class NameCompare implements Comparator <Mountain> {
        public int compare(Mountain one, Mountain two) {
          return one.name. compareTo(two. name);
      }
      }
      class HeightCompare implements Comparator <Mountain> {
        public int compare(Mountain one, Mountain two) {
    return (two. height - one. height) ;
    }

      }
      public void go() {
            mtn.add(new Mountain("Longs ", 14255));
            mtn.add(new Mountain("Elbert ", 14433));
            mtn.add(new Mountain("Maroon " , 14156));
            mtn.add(new Mountain("Castle ", 14265));

            System.out.println("as entered:\n" + mtn);
            NameCompare nc = new NameCompare();
            Collections.sort(mtn, nc);
            System.out.println("by name:\n'" + mtn);
            HeightCompare hc = new HeightCompare();
            Collections.sort(mtn, hc);
            System.out.println("by height:\n " + mtn);
          }
    public static void main(String args[]){

        sortMountains   sorting=new sortMountains();
        sorting.go();
         //error line   Mountain a=new Mountain("Everest",12121);            
    }

    }
```

The above when compiled without error line works fine but when I want to create an object of Mountain in main method it gives an error "non-static cannot be referenced from static method"

Comment: **1.** Search for [non-static cannot be referenced from static method](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=non-static+cannot+be+referenced+from+static+method&submit=search) **2.** Read some posts/answers **3.** Avoid -1's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static (one out of a million, it has lots of upvotes anyway)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `Mountain` class `static`, like so:

```
static class Mountain {
   ...
```

If you don't, every instance of `Mountain` has to have an instance of `sortMountains` associated with it. Since there's no such instance in `main()` (the method itself is `static`), the compiler won't allow you to instantiate `Mountain` there.

For further discussion, see:

- [Java: Static vs non static inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-non-static-inner-class)
- [Java inner class and static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class)

Answer (score 3):

Inner classes are just like any other members of a class. So you cannot refer a **non-static** inner class in `main()` method, it is just like you cannot refer a **non-static** global variable in `main()` method. So you can declare your class as `static` to avoid that error:

```
static class Mountain { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Mountain class is inner class, so create mountain object as :

```
sortMountains sorting=new sortMountains();
Mountain a = sorting.new Mountain("Everest",12121);
```

For your program you can not do this because Mountain class is non-static and you can not access non-static members from static methods.

So you can declare Mountain class as static and create it's object as `Mountain a = new Mountain("Everest",12121);`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, `Mountain` class it cannot be created without its enclosing class `sortMountains`. You should declare `sortMountains` static inside  `Mountain` if you want to create it in the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the Mountain class inside `sortMountains` class. In that case you can access your inner class

1. if your inner class is static (`static class Mountain{}`) or
2. Creating outer instance.new innerClass().

   `Mountain a=sorting.new Mountain("Everest",12121);`