# Trying to create a instance of class inherting from Thread, Getting error saying "No enclosing instance of type cBitrex is accessible"

Tags: java

I'm trying to have my network code run of a thread.  I have a class that inherits from Thread.  When I try to create a instance of it,

```
cSecureThread cRun=new cSecureThread();
```

I get the following error: "No enclosing instance of type cBitrex is accessible"

here is the code block

```
public class cSecureThread extends Thread { 
    String reply=null;
    String url;
    public void run()
    {
    //       GetSecureBitrexApi(url);           
    }

};


static String fn;
static String GetSecureBitrexApiThread( String url)
{

    // Line below creats error    
    cSecureThread cRun=new cSecureThread(); 
    cRun.url=url;
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX start thread XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    cRun.start();
    try {
        // wait 10 seconds to make api call
        cRun.join(1000*30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX end thread XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    fn= cRun.reply;
    return fn;    
}
```

Comment: Btw FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - No enclosing instance of type Foo is accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560600/java-no-enclosing-instance-of-type-foo-is-accessible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this whole block of code is embedded in a class called "cBitrex". A non-`static` class defined inside another class maintains a reference to an instance of that outer class. It thus cannot be used inside a `static` method of that outer class. See [here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-non-static-inner-class).

So your fix probably is to declare

```
public static class cSecureThread extends Thread {
// ...
}
```

That is, just add the `static` keyword.

(Note I say "it looks like" and "probably" because you didn't provide a whole lot of context...)