# Dependency injection and serialization Object in spring

Tags: serialization, spring-boot, spring-security, dependency-injection, spring-session

I have an application that is configured with spring security.
Everything is working as well.
The UserDetailService is:

```
@Service(value = "userDetail")
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3487495895819392L;

    @Autowired
    private IUserDetailRepository iUserDetailRepository;

    @Autowired
    private IUserRoleRepository iUserRoleRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = iUserDetailRepository.loadUserByUsername(username);
        List<UserRole> roles = iUserRoleRepository.getAllRoleByUserName(username);
        UserDetails u = new UserDetails() {

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                // return user.getEnable();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public String getUsername() {
                // return user.getUsername();
                return "reyhane";
            }

            @Override
            public String getPassword() {
                // return user.getPassword();
                return "reyhane";
            }

            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN");
                authorities.add(authority);

                return authorities;

            }
        };
        return u;
    }

}
```

After that I was forced to config spring session over this configuration for saving the context of spring security into Redis.
There exists a problem in UserDetailService.
UserDetailService have two autowired filed as shown above are:

```
@Autowired
private IUserDetailRepository iUserDetailRepository;

@Autowired
private IUserRoleRepository iUserRoleRepository;
```

This two autowired field are for getting User and User's roles information from DB.
It is interesting here that when I comment this two autowired like this:

```
//@Autowired
private IUserDetailRepository iUserDetailRepository;

//@Autowired
private IUserRoleRepository iUserRoleRepository;
```

and fill manually user and user's role.Spring session is working as well but when this two `@Autowired` exist in the class the below exception is raised:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:
>   Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception
>   is java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
>   at
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:90)
>   ~[spring-data-redis-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar:na] ... 35 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111] at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]

Everybody know that what is happen?
I do not understand what is happen.
I do not know there is what key for searching in google
I want to know what is happen between spring session and spring security and how to solve it.
Thanks for your helping

Comment: The main problem is you are using an anonymous inner class in your method. Don't do that, simply construct a new `User` instead o a new `UserDetails` and you don't need any hacks.

Comment: Please would you explain more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has actually nothing to do with those dependencies, it is due to the fact that you are using an (non `static`) inner class. You should either use an embedded `static` class or simply use the regular `User` class from Spring Security. (More on inner, (non) static embedded classes are found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-non-static-inner-class).

In short due to the fact of you using an inner classes it requires an instance of the outer class to exist. Now when serializing the `UserDetails` it will also try to serialize the outer class.

The simplest solution is to rewrite your code and use the Spring Security provided `User` class (assuming you are using Spring Security 4.2 you can use the `UserBuilder`).

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = iUserDetailRepository.loadUserByUsername(username);
    List<UserRole> roles = iUserRoleRepository.getAllRoleByUserName(username);

    return User.withUsername(user.getUsername())
                        .password(user.getPassword())
                        .disabled(!user.getEnable())
                        .roles(roles.stream().map(<convert-to-SimpleGrantedAuthority>).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .build();
}
```

If you are on Spring Security before 4.2 you can simply construct a `User` object using the constructor.

```
return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getEnable(), true, true, true, <convert-roles-to-SimpleGrantedAuthoritu>);
```

When return a concrete class it doesn't require an instance of the outer class (as it isn't an inner class) and it will not try to serialize it. It will only serialize the `User` and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem with this solution:

```
private static IUserDetailRepository userDetailRepository;

private static IUserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setUserDetailRepository(IUserDetailRepository userDetailRepository) {
        UserDetailServiceImpl.userDetailRepository = userDetailRepository;
    }

   @Autowired
   public void setUserRoleRepository(IUserRoleRepository userRoleRepository) {
       UserDetailServiceImpl.userRoleRepository = userRoleRepository;
    }
```

Comment: See the comment that isn't really a solution, but a hack to make it work.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: I already gave you that, don't use an anonymous inner class. Use the Spring Security `User` and fill the properties accordingly.