# Java Cannot infer type arguments for "Class"<>

Tags: java, generics

Hello so I have been trying to figure this problem out for a bit now and I googled. I have found posts on here with the same problem, but they didn't really help me.

In my JUnit test the call for 
PaymentBatchProcessor checkProcessor = new PaymentBatchProcessor<>();

causes "Cannot infer type arguments for PaymentBatchProcessor<>"

I just learned about Generics and that's why I'm having such a hard time implementig it. I understand the general concept of Generics.

```
    public class PaymentBatchProcessor <T extends Payment> {

        // Variables
        private T payment;

        List <T> listOfPayments;

        // Constructor
        public PaymentBatchProcessor(T payment) {
            this.payment = payment;
            this.listOfPayments = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // add method
        public void add(T payment) {

            this.listOfPayments.add(payment);
        }

        // getMax method
        public double getMax () {
            // Placeholder
            double maxAmount = 0.0;

            for( T payment : listOfPayments) {
                // displaying each payment to console
                System.out.println(payment);

                // If current payment is more then current maxAmount
                //      assign new highest amount
                if(payment.getAmount() > maxAmount) {
                    maxAmount = payment.getAmount();
                }
            }
            // Return highest amount
            return maxAmount;   
        }// END OF getMax()


        // getTotal method
        public double getTotal() {

            // Accumulator
            double total = 0.0;

            // Add each payment amount to total
            for( T payment : listOfPayments) {
                total +=  payment.getAmount();
            }

            return total;
        }// END OF getTotal()

        // getSize method
        public int getSize() {
            // Return size of list
            return listOfPayments.size();
        }

}// END OF PAYMENTBATCHPROCESSOR



//Interface
public interface Payment {

        public  double getAmount();
        public void setAmount(double amount);


//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    // Check class
    public class Check implements Payment{
        // Variable
        private double amount;

        // Constructor
        public Check (double amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        // Getter and Setter
        public double getAmount() {
            return this.amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(double amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }// END OF CHECK

//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    public class IOU implements Payment {
        // Variable
        private double amount;

        // Constructor
        public IOU (double amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        // Getter and Setter
        public double getAmount() {
            return this.amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(double amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }// END OF IOU
}
// +++++++++++++ PROBLEM AREA +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.Test;



public class TestGenerics
{

    @Test
    public void testProcessorAsCheck()
    {
        PaymentBatchProcessor<Check> checkProcessor = new PaymentBatchProcessor<>();

        checkProcessor.add( new Check(5.00) );
        checkProcessor.add (new Check(10.00) );

        assertEquals(15, checkProcessor.getTotal(), 2);
        assertEquals(10, checkProcessor.getMax(), 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorAsIOU()
    {
        PaymentBatchProcessor<IOU> processor = new PaymentBatchProcessor<>();

        processor.add( new IOU(22.54) );
        processor.add( new IOU(22.55) );

        assertEquals(45.09, processor.getTotal(), 2);
        assertEquals(22.55, processor.getMax(), 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorAsPayment()
    {
        Payment iou = new IOU(11.22);
        Payment iou2 = new Check(22.11);

        PaymentBatchProcessor<Payment> processor = new PaymentBatchProcessor<>();

        processor.add(iou);
        processor.add(iou2);

        assertEquals(33.33, processor.getTotal(), 2);
        assertEquals(22.11, processor.getMax(), 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorAsPaymentWithEmptyList()
    {
        PaymentBatchProcessor<Payment> processor = new PaymentBatchProcessor<>();

        assertEquals(0, processor.getTotal(), 2);
        assertNull(null, processor.getMax());
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorHelperAsPayment()
    {
        ArrayList<Payment> list = new ArrayList<Payment>();

        list.add( new Check(10.00) );
        list.add( new Check(5.00) );
        list.add( new IOU(1.00) );

        assertEquals(10, PaymentProcessorHelper.<Payment> getMax(list).getAmount(), 2);
        assertEquals(16, PaymentProcessorHelper.<Payment> getSum(list), 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorHelperAsPaymentEmptyList()
    {
        ArrayList<Payment> list = new ArrayList<Payment>();

        assertNull(PaymentProcessorHelper.<Payment> getMax(list));
        assertEquals(0, PaymentProcessorHelper.<Payment> getSum(list), 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorHelperAsCheck()
    {
        ArrayList<Check> list = new ArrayList<Check>();

        list.add( new Check(10.00) );
        list.add( new Check(5.00) );

        assertEquals(10, PaymentProcessorHelper.<Check> getMax(list).getAmount(), 2);
        assertEquals(15, PaymentProcessorHelper.<Check> getSum(list), 2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorHelperAsIOU()
    {
        ArrayList<IOU> list = new ArrayList<IOU>();

        list.add( new IOU(11.22) );
        list.add( new IOU(22.11) );

        assertEquals(22.11, PaymentProcessorHelper.<IOU> getMax(list).getAmount(), 2);
        assertEquals(33.11, PaymentProcessorHelper.<IOU> getSum(list), 2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You should provide a minimal example, which showcases your problem. I put your code into my IDE and it compiles fine. You need to provide code, which suffers from the compilation error, which you describe.

Comment: I added the JUnit code that gives me problems at the end. Sorry

Comment: What Java version are you using? Also, what IDE?

Comment: I just added it. I'm using Eclipse IDE, version idk, newest? the PaymentProcessorHelper is for the same class as PaymentBatchProcessor just with the two generic methods mentioned.

Comment: Your JUnit tests show a different compiler error: `GenericClassPart1` is not an enclosing class. Can you confirm ? If yes, than you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-inner-class

Comment: I get java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: "Cannot infer type arguments for PaymentBatchProcessor<>" for each testProcessorAsCheck, AsIOU, and AsPayment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `PaymentBatchProcessor` you have defined a constructor that takes a `Payment` as an argument, but in the tests you try to use a no-arguments constructor `new PaymentBatchProcessor<>()`, which doesn't exist.

You either need to define a no-arguments constructor or provide an argument to the constructors in your tests.

> And I'm also trying to make getMax and getTotal a generic method

Based on the code in your question I don't really understand why you would want to do that.

> I tried making them public static < T >

I think you have misunderstood something about generics (and also the `static` modifier) here.

It doesn't look like `getMax` and `getTotal` should ever return anything other than `double` and they don't take any arguments so there is no issue of handling different types of inputs.
And you can't make those methods `static` because they operate on instance variables (not class variables).

Comment: You have only posted code about `PaymentBatchProcessor` not `PaymentProcessorHelper` in your question. 
If you tried to make the methods of `PaymentBatchProcessor` generic then that's probably wrong.
If you tried to make methods of `PaymentProcessorHelper` generic and it didn't work then you have probably copied something over from `PaymentBatchProcessor` that you shouldn't have.  
Either way I suggest working through this tutorial if you haven't already https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/