# Enclosing instance required that contains outerclass.innerclass

Tags: java

`Student.Student_Card obj4 = Student.new Student_Card(namess, idss, true);`

Student class is an outer class and Studen_Card is nested class,when i am running this code i am getting error that:
 an enclosing instance that contains Student.Student_Card is required

Comment: try new Student.Student_Card()

Comment: Hi! ..put the `new ` in front! ..this will fix the issue or at least produce another error (message).

Comment: `StudentCard`. Why add an `_`? Java class names are already camel case by convention. Also, why use an inner-class? And is there some reason we can't see your code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this:

Student.Student_Card obj4 =new Student.Student_Card(namess, idss, true);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the error, mark the inner class with `static`, as so: `static class Student_Card`

Otherwise, note that inner classes require an instance of the outer class, like so:

```
Student student = new Student();
Student_Card studentCard = student.new Student_Card()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Student_Card` class is not static, then you need an instance of Student in order to create it.

```
Student student = new Student();
Student.Student_Card obj4 = student.new Student_Card(namess, idss, true);
```

If you will make class `Student_Card static, then you don't need any reference to your Student class at all, this will work:

```
Student.Student_Card card=  new Student.Student_Card(namess, idss, true);
```

You can read more in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353309/java-static-vs-inner-class).